Is it possible to convert a C# model to XML and upload it to FTP server without local temp file?
I intend to use XmlSerializer and FluentFTP library to do that, but I can't be bothered to create any local temp XML file.

Basically, most (XML or whatever) APIs either:

returns its own Stream, which you can pass to FluentFTP FtpClient.UploadStream.
https://github.com/robinrodricks/FluentFTP/wiki/File-Transfer

can write to a provided Stream, which you can create using FluentFTP FtpClient.OpenWrite.


With XmlSerializer and FtpClient.OpenWrite it would be like (untested):
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TheModel));
using (var stream = ftpClient.OpenWrite("/remote/path/model.xml"))
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
{
    serializer.Serialize(writer, model);
}


Thanks for your answer. Once I invoke ftpClient.OpenWrite, will the empty XML file be generated on the FTP server? How can I avoid to create some incomplete files  if there is a problem during Serialize.

If you want to upload only once the serialization completed, then you need to serialize into memory (i.e. to MemoryStream) and upload only afterwards.

I think the code below will solve my problem
TheModel model = new TheModel();
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TheModel));
serializer.Serialize(memoryStream, model);
FtpClient client = new FtpClient();
client.AutoConnect();
client.UploadStream(memoryStream, "", FtpRemoteExists.NoCheck, true);


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
